# How to find object in array of objects?

Tags: node.js, express

Here is my code in Node:

The results will always be "No" even if the objects are the same object. i tried with  "==" and same answer - "no"

````
  const recipe = await getRecipes(req.params.id); \\ID
  let user = await User.findById(req.user._id); \\ user
  user.recipes.forEach((item) => {

    console.log(item._id); \\ 5f196683308447452cd2c018
    console.log(recipe._id); \\ 5f196683308447452cd2c018
    
    if (item._id === recipe._id) {
      console.log("yes");
    } else {
      console.log("no");
    }
  });
});  ```
````

Comment: You would get *a lot* of `"no"` and at most one `"yes"`. Are you sure you're not overlooking it?

Comment: i really dont understand you.

Comment: You are looping through many recipes. At most one of them will have the same ID as `recipe._id` - that one would print `"yes"` in the console. Everything else would print `"no"`. Are you sure you're not just missing the `"yes"`?

Comment: i had only 1 recipe in that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It keeps outputting 'no' because you are comparing 2 different Mongo ObjectId objects.

For example, `console.log({a:1}  === {a:1})` is false since they are 2 different objects.

If you really wanted to check by the ObjectId, you could do:

`item._id.toString() === recipe._id.toString()`

Comment: Glad to have helped! :)

Comment: other than using forEach you should consider using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method.

Comment: can you give me example for that?

Comment: [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) or [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) just optimizes the search a bit since it simply returns the first element that it finds instead of going through each element in the array by using forEach()

Comment: how do i use the findIndex instead of foreach?